# For Loop for within-subjects ggplot with 2 y axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create multiple different plots in R at the same time using ggplot. Each one represents a different group in my dataset (named in the group variable). These groups have had their means and sd's measured over multiple years. I am trying to create graphs that shows how both the mean and sd have changed over the years for each different group.

My data look like this (this is an abbreviated example):

```
group <- c("liberals", "liberals","liberals","liberals","women", "women", "women", "men", "men","men","men")
year <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 1987, 1988, 1990, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006)
mean <- c(50.21, 50.44, 58.95, 56.23, 20.21, 20.44, 21.44, 90.55, 90.56, 93.44, 90.22)
sd <- c(20.31, 20.44, 23.55, 22.56, 1.23, 1.44, 1.55, 12.31, 14.32, 15.23, 12.53)
dat <- cbind(group, year, mean, sd)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

I want to have a different plot for each group (liberals, women, men) that has the year on the X axis, with the Y axis showing both the SD's and Means for that year (two separate lines). This is my plot-creating code as it is now:

```
dat$Year=as.numeric(dat$year)
dat$Mean = as.numeric(dat$mean)
dat$sd = as.numeric(dat$sd)
uniq_groups = unique(dat$group)

for (i in uniq_groups) {
p= ggplot(dat=dat, aes(x= as.numeric(year))) +
  geom_line(aes(y= as.numeric(mean), color = "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y= as.numeric(sd), color = "blue")) + 
  ggtitle(i)
ggsave(p, file=paste0("plot_", i,".png"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
}
```

Currently, my code produces multiple wonky plots that all look the same like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1n5D.png) , with the exception of having different groups labeled at the top. I think that I am getting all the groups combined together in these graphs.

I am wondering how I can change my code so that each graph corresponds with only one group and its different means and sd's over time?

Comment: Welcome to SO. accepting answers helps the community know what doesn't need anymore attention or what still needs an answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach using a list to save the different groups (`split()`) with a function for plots and then use `mapply()` to avoid the loop:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Create list
List <- split(dat,dat$group)
#Plot
myfun <- function(x){
  val <- unique(x$group)
  #Format
  x %>% select(year,mean,sd) %>%
    mutate(mean=as.numeric(as.character(mean))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= year,y=value,color=name,group=name)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(val)+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
          axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
          legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
          legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
          plot.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',hjust = 0.5)) -> G
  return(G)
}
#Apply
Lplot <- lapply(List, myfun)
#Export
mapply(ggsave,Lplot,file=paste0("plot_", names(Lplot),".png"),
           width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ChuckP Yeah, maybe the data. I will check!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell it to not pull all the data `dat` at once. `dat[dat$group==uniq_groups[i],]` will allow the group to be one unique group at a time, based on `i`.

```
uniq_groups = unique(dat$group)

for (i in 1:length(uniq_groups)) {
p= ggplot(dat=dat[dat$group==uniq_groups[i],], aes(x= as.numeric(year))) +
  geom_line(aes(y= as.numeric(mean), color = "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y= as.numeric(sd), color = "blue")) + 
  ggtitle(uniq_groups[i])
ggsave(p, file=paste0("plot_", i,".png"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
}
```

Comment: @Kate Glad it helped. Please consider marking the answer as accepted, if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidy solution with some aesthetic cleanup as well...

First you had some capitalization issues with your `as.numeric` lets fix those

```r
dat$sd = as.numeric(dat$sd)
dat$mean = as.numeric(dat$mean)
dat$year = as.numeric(dat$year)
dat$group <- factor(dat$group)
str(dat)
#> 'data.frame':    11 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "liberals","men",..: 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ year : num  1990 1991 1992 1994 1987 ...
#>  $ mean : num  50.2 50.4 59 56.2 20.2 ...
#>  $ sd   : num  20.31 20.44 23.55 22.56 1.23 ...
```

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
```

Make a list of plots called `plot_list` with `purrr::map` also splitting by group as in other solutions.  Cleaning up legend and making title nice

```r
plot_list <- 
   dat %>%
   split(.$group) %>%
   map(~ ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = year)) +
          geom_line(aes(y = mean, color = "red"), show.legend = FALSE) + 
          geom_line(aes(y = sd, color = "blue"), show.legend = FALSE) + 
          ggtitle(stringr::str_to_title(.$group)))
```

To print them all

```r
plot_list
#> $liberals
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now to save them all with the names you like we'll use `map2` and get the names from the list itself

```r
map2(plot_list,
      names(plot_list),
      ~ ggsave(plot = .x, 
                        device = "png",
                        filename = paste0("plot_", .y,".png"), 
                        width = 14, 
                        height = 10, 
                        units = "cm"))
```

Your original data:

```r
group <- c("liberals", "liberals","liberals","liberals","women", "women", "women", "men", "men","men","men")
year <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 1987, 1988, 1990, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006)
mean <- c(50.21, 50.44, 58.95, 56.23, 20.21, 20.44, 21.44, 90.55, 90.56, 93.44, 90.22)
sd <- c(20.31, 20.44, 23.55, 22.56, 1.23, 1.44, 1.55, 12.31, 14.32, 15.23, 12.53)
dat <- cbind(group, year, mean, sd)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
```